# FORM to PHP to overlay?

Tags: php, forms

My dilemma:

I have a search form on my main page that I want to submit to php search function that then posts its results to an overlay without leaving the main page.

This is my form code:

```
<form method="post" id="searchform" action="external-content.php" >
        <div>
        <input class="input-text" name="keyword" id="s" value="Enter your text here..." onFocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your text here...') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your text here...';}" type="text" />

        <input id="searchsubmit" value="Search" type="submit" />

        </div>
</form>
```

Here is my overlay code:

```
<div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
        <div class="contentWrap"></div>
    </div>
<script src="js/overlay/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("a[rel]").overlay({

        mask: 'darkgrey',
        effect: 'apple',

        onBeforeLoad: function() {
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

The overlay works perfectly when I am just using a simple button to trigger the overlay. And the form calls the PHP function and shows the data I want to show, but it opens the data in a different tab.

Would I edit the form to make the results show in the overlay (If so, how?), or is there something in the script I need to adjust to make these two elements work together?

Comment: @user3230921 Did you get a solution for this??? I need the same

Answer (score 0):

The two are not connected yet. You need an onsubmit event in the form, that loads the data from the server.

```
<form method="post" id="searchform" action="" onsubmit="showOverlay(); return false">
```

Make sure you return false, so the Browser does not send the form itself.

---

Tip:

```
<input class="input-text" name="keyword" id="s" value="Enter your text here..." onFocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your text here...') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your text here...';}" type="text" />
```

Can be

```
<input class="input-text" name="keyword" id="s" placeholder="Enter your text here..." type="text" />
```

Comment: colburton,

Still opens php data in a new window instead opening the overlay with the data in it.

Comment: For a new window to open you must have something like window.open or target="_new" or target="_blank". Remove that